# Is there a regex, to replace the digits in the string with # and remove all the characters which are not digits

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string that will have digits in that, we need to remove all the characters which are not digits and replace the digits with #

I have written a regex, its able to replace the digits with #, but I could not find the regex to remove the characters which are not digits.

```
import re
def replace_digits(string):
    m=re.sub("\d","#",string)
```

Examples :

`234` -> `###`

`a2b3c4` -> `###`

`abc` -> `<empty string>`

`#2a$#b%c%561#` -> `####`

Comment: Ex 1: A = 234                Output: ###
Ex 2: A = a2b3c4             Output: ###
Ex 3: A = abc                Output:   (empty string)
Ex 5: A = #2a$#b%c%561#      Output: ####

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want use regex? looks like can be done easily without: `'#' * len(x for x in s if x.isdigit())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

examples = ['234',
'a2b3c4',
'abc',
'#2a$#b%c%561#']

for example in examples:
    new_s = '#' * len(re.sub(r'\D', '', example))
    print('Input = {} Output = {}'.format(example, new_s))
```

Prints:

```
Input = 234 Output = ###
Input = a2b3c4 Output = ###
Input = abc Output = 
Input = #2a$#b%c%561# Output = ####
```

EDIT (without regex - thanks @CorentinLimier)

```
for example in examples:
    new_s = ''.join('#' for c in example if c.isdigit())
    print('Input = {} Output = {}'.format(example, new_s))
```

EDIT (add @Tomerikoo 's answer from the comments):

```
for example in examples:
    new_s = '#' * len([x for x in example if x.isdigit()])
    print('Input = {} Output = {}'.format(example, new_s))
```

Comment: No need to use a meta sequence inside a group. instead of `[^\d]` simply use `\D`

Comment: Imo there is a more pythonic way to code your idea `''.join('#' if c.isdigit() else '' for c in s)` it is more readable

Comment: @AndrejKesely Tomerikoos non regex solution in the comments above is probablyt slightly more readable (and less confusing for beginners since it doesn't use `((`) then the non regex solution suggested by Corentin.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Added it to the response. But I edited it slightly - you cannot do `len()` on plain generator expression, so I enclosed it in `[]`

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thanks for that. I wasn't sure if it is necessary or not as I know that for printing for example it can be ommited. As to @CorentinLimier 's version, I believe it can be simplified by removing the else part and moving the if to the end: `''.join('#' for c in example if c.isdigit())`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes, you have right. I edited it. Now op has rich options of answers to choose from ;)

Comment: I have been searching the internet on regex patterns to get good understanding, but could not find an easy one. Could anyone suggest some link where I can get sufficient practical knowledge on regex patterns in python.